# How can I estimate square footage of fencing for stain?

Tags: fence, staining, measuring

I have a fence that looks like the following:
[image]

I plan on staining this fence with a [paint sprayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIROa.jpg) and [this stain product](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Sikkens-Translucent-Cetol-SRD-Exterior-Wood-Finish-Butternut-1-Gal-SIK240-072-01/203218741). The product notes that one gallon will cover `Coverage Area (sq. ft.) 250 ft²`. Can someone help me determine how to calculate the number of gallons I would need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprayers make the job much quicker and easier, however there will be a lot more waste. Take the fence height X the length X two (sides) and you will have an apx of the square feet.  Example  4ft high X 100 feet long X 2 sides = 800 square feet. 800/250= 3.2 gals.

Realistically, if you are careful and try to hit the pickets and not waste as much on the spaces, you may use a slight bit less. Keep in mind, if you are using a stock color, you can return unused/unopened product for a refund at most stores.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure if fencing like this required some type of special estimation. LXWXsides is no problem. About 8 gallons needed for my job, now I can buy the big 5gal bucket!